# What is Windows PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

- What is it for?
- How do I use it?
- How is it different from the regular Command Prompt?
- Is there anything I should know before starting to use it?
- Any awesome things you can do with it that a super user should know about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514492/what-is-windows-powershell

Comment: That link fretje is good.  Just ignore the accepted answer though and look at the 20+ rated one.

Comment: Um... what does this have to do with stackoverflow? Is Windows PowerShell programming related?

Comment: Be sure to look at the answer with the most up votes not the accepted answer.

Comment: And yes it is programming related.

Comment: I don't think the Windows-7 tag is appropriate. The question is not W7 specific and powershell certainly isn't.

Comment: @EBGreen: changed it to [windows]

Comment: Windows Powershell can be good to user for "superusers" too, as it's easier to navigate, and closer to a unix console (for users familiar with it). It's not necessarily programming related only.

Comment: I also have to disagree. Powershell is for Developers, SysAdmins and PowerUsers alike, and I see nothing wrong with this particular question being asked on SU. In fact I have even seen some PowerShell answer pop-up which is great to see.

Comment: I can write a fully functional event driven GUI program in it so that makes it programming related to me.

Comment: Oh, and when I say it is programming related that in no way means it is not SU related as well.

Comment: @EBGreen - Agreed - Kudos to you for the Powershell answers :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell

> Windows PowerShell is an extensible
>   command-line shell and associated
>   scripting language from Microsoft. It
>   was released in 2006 and is currently
>   available for Windows XP SP2/SP3,
>   Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista,
>   and is included in Windows Server 2008
>   as an optional feature. Windows
>   PowerShell 2.0 was released with
>   Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.
>   It is going to be backported to
>   previous supported platforms Windows
>   XP SP3, Windows Server 2003 SP2,
>   Windows Vista SP1 and Windows Server
>   2008.[4](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+tricks)
>
> Windows PowerShell integrates with the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework and provides
>   an environment to perform
>   administrative tasks by execution of
>   cmdlets (pronounced commandlets),
>   which are specialized .NET classes
>   implementing a particular operation;
>   scripts, which are compositions of
>   cmdlets along with imperative logic;
>   executables, which are standalone
>   applications; or by instantiating
>   regular .NET classes.[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622902/powershell-tips-tricks-for-developers) These work
>   by accessing data in different data
>   stores, like the filesystem or
>   registry, which are made available to
>   the PowerShell runtime via Windows
>   PowerShell providers.
>
> Windows PowerShell also provides a
>   hosting mechanism with which the
>   Windows PowerShell runtime can be
>   embedded inside other applications,
>   which can then leverage Windows
>   PowerShell functionality to implement
>   certain operations, including those
>   exposed via the graphical interface.
>   This capability has been utilized by
>   Microsoft Exchange Server 2007[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622902/powershell-tips-tricks-for-developers)
>   to expose its management functionality
>   as PowerShell cmdlets and providers
>   and implement the graphical management
>   tools as PowerShell hosts which invoke
>   the necessary cmdlets. Other Microsoft
>   applications including Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2008[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622902/powershell-tips-tricks-for-developers) also expose their
>   management interface via PowerShell
>   cmdlets. In the future, graphical
>   interface-based management
>   applications on Windows will be
>   layered on top of Windows PowerShell.
>
> Windows PowerShell includes its own
>   extensive, console-based help,
>   reminiscent of man pages in Unix
>   shells via the Get-Help cmdlet.

Searching Stackoverflow using [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+tricks) I've found the following:

- [What is Windows PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514492/what-is-windows-powershell)
- [How to get started with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559/how-to-get-started-with-powershell)
- [How do you use PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722/how-do-you-use-powershell)
- [PowerShell Tips & Tricks for Developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622902/powershell-tips-tricks-for-developers)

Again on serverfault using [this search](https://serverfault.com/search?q=powershell+tricks) I've found the following:

- [Powershell? Do you use it? Show me some cool sysadmin things i can do with it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/13493/powershell-do-you-use-it-show-me-some-cool-sysadmin-things-i-can-do-with-it)
- [What are some good resources for learning PowerShell scripting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/4352/what-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-powershell-scripting)
- [What’s your favorite Powershell command or script for system administration?](https://serverfault.com/questions/978/whats-your-favorite-powershell-command-or-script-for-system-administration)
- [Common PowerShell Pitfalls](https://serverfault.com/questions/42675/common-powershell-pitfalls)

Answer (score 5):

The "Great Powershell Heresy", a.k.a. greatest innovation of PS over the UNIX-style shells you may be familiar with (tcsh, bash, etc.) is this:

Pipelines in "all those other shells" pass strings around.
Pipelines in PowerShell pass objects around.

Because of this, PowerShell might be "harder" to learn, i.e. it requires learning new technology, and doing detailed stuff requires more knowledge of what's going on... but, once learned, it is VASTLY simpler to write shell scripts that can actually be read by other people (or you, 5 years later)... and those scripts are far less likely to "break" when something else on the system is changed.

Answer (score -3):

Quick and simple for the non power-user reading this:

Unless you are a system administrator you will not need Powershell.  All it is is a collection of powerful shell commands for an administrator to use in the administration of Windows Server and client computers and the creation of scripts.

Comment: I use PS at home and on my family's computers for generic file activities. It is in no way limited to admins.

Comment: I also use many admin tools in my day to day home computer use, but I am a network administrator and have always been a power user.  Most people just surfing around this site are going to look at the wiki reference and skip right past, this is for them.... thus the note at the top.

Comment: Ehh...I start with the assumption that users at superuser.com are...you know...super users.

Comment: Most users of Google.com are not...  and by that logic are all users of WebMD.com.. you know.. doctors?

Comment: That's fine, but I doubt that WebMD's FAQ starts with "WebMD is a site for Doctors". Whereas SU's FAQ starts with "Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users."